# how to form an array of arrays in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to make an array of arrays like

```
{ [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55] }
```

in jQuery ?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var row = 4;
    var items = [];
    var total = [];
    $('#test tr:eq(' + row + ') td').each(function(colindex, col) {
        //alert(colindex);
        t = $(this).contents();
        items.length = 0;
        $.each(t, function(i, val) {
            if (val.tagName != 'BR') {
                if (val.innerHTML == undefined) {
                    items.push(val.data);
                }
                else
                    items.push(val.innerHTML);
            }
            //alert(items.toString());
        });
        total.push(items);
    });
    alert(total.toString());
});
```

iIn the above code I'm trying to create a array `Total()` with the elements as arrays (`item()`), but how ever the `Total()` array has only one object that too the last `item()` array.

Comment: { [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55] } => Object containing arrays. [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55]] => Array containing arrays

Comment: @stecb: `{ [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55] }` is an invalid object literal, not an object containing arrays (it doesn't have any property names). But yes, the correct notation for an array of arrays when written as a literal would indeed be `[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55]]`.

Comment: You're absolutely right T.J. :) ..ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're reusing the same `items` array on each loop. Instead, create a new `items` array:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var row = 4;
    var items;       // <============= Don't need to initialize here
    var total = [];
    $('#test tr:eq(' + row + ') td').each(function(colindex, col) {
        //alert(colindex);
        t = $(this).contents();
        items = [];  // <============== Create each new `items` array here
        $.each(t, function(i, val) {
            if (val.tagName != 'BR') {
                if (val.innerHTML == undefined) {
                    items.push(val.data);
                }
                else
                    items.push(val.innerHTML);
            }
            //alert(items.toString());
        });
        total.push(items);
    });
    alert(total.toString());
});
```

When you set the `length` property of an array to `0`, you're removing all of its array elements but it's still the same array, so you ended up pushing the same array onto your `totals` array repeatedly.

Comment: @deathcaller: Just to flag it up, see @guffa's note about your `if (val.innerHTML == undefined)` check. Really best to do `if (typeof val.innerHTML === 'undefined')` (note the `===` rather than just `==`, although in this case, it doesn't matter all that much).

Answer (score 1):

Move the creation of the items array into the outer loop so that you create a new array for each iteration. Otherwise you will be adding the same array to `total` over and over, so you will end up with an array full of references to the same array, which contains only the values from the last iteration.

Don't use the `undefined` "constant", as it's not a constant. Check the type of the property instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var row = 4;
  var total = [];
  $('#test tr:eq(' + row + ') td').each(function(colindex, col) {
    t = $(this).contents();
    // create a new array for each iteration:
    var items = [];
    $.each(t, function(i, val) {
      if (val.tagName != 'BR') {
        if (typeof val.innerHTML == 'undefined') {
          items.push(val.data);
        } else {
          items.push(val.innerHTML);
        }
      }
    });
    total.push(items);
  });
  alert(total.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, an array of arrays literal should have two sets of `[]`, not mixed `[]` and `{}`: `[ [1,2,3],[2,3,4],[2,34,55] ]`

Also, instead of

```
items.length = 0;
```

do this:

```
var items = [];
```

What you're doing now is kind of like trying to expand your friend's circle of acquaintances by taking another person and introducing him to her repeatedly, only changing his clothes, wig and fake moustache every time. Despite the different looks, your friend will only get one new acquaintance.